# Checking if a file is behind htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is there anyway to check if a file, in my case an image file, is behind htaccess?

I am trying to echo out the path to an image src where in some cases the file will be behind an htaccess required authentication. In that case I want it to display nothing. Right now, it presents the login/password prompt because I am referencing that image.

Sample:

folder2 is behind required authentication

```
$folders = ['folder1','folder2'];

foreach($folders as $folder){

    if(is_readable($folder.'/thumb.png'))
        echo "<img src='{$folder}/thumb.png' />";
    else
        echo 'img not found';

}
```

I have tried is_readable and file_exists, both seem to still present the prompt.

edit: htaccess file

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/.../.htpasswd
AuthName "Please Log In"
require valid-user
```

Comment: can you show your htaccess code?

Comment: just remove authentication from those folders from where you dont want to check

Comment: hm well anyway if you try to load the image from a protected folder it´s just going to show nothing, and you'll have a 401 in the console, nothing else

Comment: I am unable to remove the authentication from those folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using something like cURL, you could send an HTTP request and see the request code.  If it shows 401 or 403, it's unauthorized.  Otherwise, it's fine.

**UPDATE:**  It would be simpler just to use the `get_headers()` method for this.  The first item in the array will be the response code, which you can handle as outlined above.

Comment: The principle is sound but `get_headers()` might be simpler : http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php - the HTTP response header is the first item in the returned array.

Comment: This sounds good, but I agreed with CD0001, ended up going with get_headers() solution, then just checking for 404 and 401 errors. Sanders response would work well too. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the .htaccess files and look for the require word, or do something smarter depending on how your .htaccess files might vary:

Something like this:

```
if(strpos(file_get_contents($folder."/.htaccess"), "require") === false)
{
    // show image
}
```

Of course you'll want to cache the output for each folder.